"The tired fireman found the building ablaze", is "ablaze" predicative adjective at there?
I have encountered a question which asks which sentence doesn't include a predicative adjective and according to the question this sentence includes a predicative adjective,

The tired fireman found the building ablaze.

I couldn't understand how the "the building ablaze" describes fireman or even see "find" as a linking verb.

Yes, the adjective "ablaze" is objective predicative complement of "found". It's obligatory for this meaning of "found", which is "discovered". Note that "ablaze" only occurs in postpostive position.

This question is similar to: In ‘catch me off guard’, is the ‘off guard’ an objective complement or adjective phrase?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. In your example, depictive object-orientated secondary predication. // 'The building is ablaze' shows the prototypical predicative adjective.

@zehir The adjective "ablaze" is undoubtedly objective predicative complement of "found", which here means "discovered".

And the reason it appears only in postpositive position is that it is an adjective formed by the coalescing of a prepositional phrase, "on blaze", into a single word, as with "on fire" -> afire. "The arsonist set the building afire".


The tired fireman found the building ablaze.

Yes, the adjective "ablaze" is objective predicative complement of "found".
It's predicative because it relates to a predicand, here "the building", and it's a complement because it is obligatory for this meaning of "found", which is "discovered".
It's important to distinguish your example, which is a complex transitive construction, with the complex intransitive type found in examples like "The building was ablaze.
Note that "ablaze" only occurs in postpositive or predicative position.

This is a typical construction of verbs, but not all verbs; only certain verbs have it and you have to check in a dictionary in order to find out whether or not it is possible with the verb at hand. It is possible for "to find".

(OALD, 2008 edition) find IN UNEXPECTED SITUATIONS 7 To discover sb/sth/yourself doing something or in a particular situation, especially when this is unexpected: […] [VN-ADJ]

You may find your illness hard to accept


In the construction "[VN-ADJ], V stands for the verb, and N the object. The verb is not a linking verb but a transitive verb.
Other such verbs (there are many of them)

consider: She considered him lucky. ("lucky" applies to "him")
deem: He deemed the evidence sufficient. ("sufficient" applies to "evidence")
suppose: They supposed him dead. ("dead" applies to "him")
knock: The blow knocked me flat. ("flat" applies to "me")
grow: Grow your hair long. ("long" applies to "hair")



The tired fireman found the building ablaze. ("ablaze" applies to "building")
The tired fireman found that the building was ablaze.


In some cases you can say " S V that < O (N) as S of that clause > was ADJ"

She considered that he was lucky.
He deemed that the evidence was sufficient.
They supposed that he was dead.

For the last two examples,  resultative constructions, the equivalent formulation  with a that clause is not possible.

As i understand "the building ablaze" can't be a predicative adjective because found isn't a linking verb but a transitive verb is it correct ?

@Zehir It has to be because "the building" is considered to be an object; linking verbs have no object; "the building" is what the subject finds, although it is found in a particular state. One could say "The tired fireman "arrived and beheld" the building as it was burning."; the idea of an object is perhaps now more evident, but there is no perfect equivalent.
